# When are/ if recursive identities used?

Tags: functional-equations

Due to the fact that $$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)\sin \pi x=\pi$$

is this necessarily true:

$$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)\sin(\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(1-x)\sin(\cdots))=\pi$$

Is this at all used as a tactic to create different identities in general?
(The Reflection Property example was just to illustrate my point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follows is what I assume you are asking. Taking

$$A = \Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)\sin(z\pi) = \pi$$

then rather trivially substituting $A$ for $\pi$

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)\sin(z\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)\sin(\pi z)) = \pi$$

Continually making the substitution for $\pi$ on the inside of the $\sin$ with $A$ produces the exact same effect. Wherein you have a rather trivial limit.

written more concisely using two variables we have

$$\phi(z,s) = \Gamma(1+z)\Gamma(1-z)\sin(s)$$

that

$$\sin(\phi(z,\phi(z,\phi(z,...(n\,times)...\phi(z,\pi z)) = \pi \sin(\pi z)$$

namely that your limit is true, but rather more interestingly that

$$\sin(\Gamma(1+z)\Gamma(1-z)\sin(\Gamma(1+z)\Gamma(1-z)\sin(... = \pi \sin\pi z$$

which seems rather bewildering to be honest.

Edit:

As to if this technique is used in functional identities: On infinite processes similar techniques are used (infinite products, infinite sums), however modified from the above (respectfully if multiplication or addition, instead of composition, is used). On infinite compositions (compositions of a function with itself infinite times as in how I wrote my answer) yes this technique is used occasionally. However it's usually much more diverse in the requirements of the proof.